# .setViseble only actualy shows(works) when I expand the window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm currently working on my first Java program with a graphical user interface

The main objective of this project is to create a program for project and task management. I'm currently facing challenges related to field validation, not with the validation process itself, but with effectively communicating validation feedback to the user

This is how I designed it, with error messages displayed under the mandatory fields

[DesignInsideIDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZQfl.png)

And I coded this method to hid the error messages

```
public void hideErrorFileds(){
        lblDeadlineMandatory.setVisible(false);
        lblNameMandatory.setVisible(false);
    }
```

And put it on the constructor

```
public class NewTaskDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    // Creating variable for the controller
    TaskController controller;
    Project project;
    
    public NewTaskDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        
        initComponents();
        hideErrorFileds();  
        
        // Starting a new instance for the controller
        controller = new TaskController();     
    }
```

In the 'save button clicked' event, a check is performed on the mandatory fields, and if any mandatory field is empty, an error message appears below the empty field.

```
                if(txtName.getText().isEmpty()){
                    lblNameMandatory.setVisible(true);
                }
                
                if(formattedTxtDeadline.getText().isEmpty()){
                    lblDeadlineMandatory.setVisible(true);
                }
```

Now that the problem starts, when I run the window, it appears to be normal, with the fields hidden correctly.

[theWindowExecuted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH0Ax.png)

When I click to save without filling in the fields, visually, nothing seems to happen. After a few minutes, I discovered that, after I trigger the error (and nothing happens), if I click on the window's border as if to 'resize' it (enlarge the window), that's when the error messages for the fields appear.

[executedWindowWithError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FECHs.png)

II've already tried two things.

First, I tried increasing the minimum window size (it didn't work)

And then I came up with a workaround. Instead of using **`.setVisible(false)`**, I used **`.setForeground(white)`** to make it 'invisible' by blending it with the background. This way, during validation, it would change its color to red.

But the way the layout starts is bothering me a lot, and I wanted help to see if I'm doing something wrong.

The image below shows how the window starts with the white foreground, having this large gap where the error message should be 'invisible'

WhiteForeground

Comment: 1) try invoking revalidate() and repaint() on the panel 2) Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem.